# Create a Dummy/Categorial Variable based on Day of Week in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R and is attempting to test out the "January Effect" to see if there is higher returns on Mondays.

I think this involves creating a dummy variable `monday` that takes the value of `1` if it is a Monday and `0` otherwise.

**Question:** How can the dummy variable `monday` be created, given that `spyReturns` contains the dates.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols('SPY', from='2015-01-01')
spyReturns <- dailyReturn(SPY)

monday <- #?? How to identify mondays?
lm(spyReturns ~ factor(monday))
```

Comment: In help page of `strptime` (`?strptime`), see arguments `%u` and `%w`. Something like `format(index(spyReturns), "%w") == "1"` should give you the information you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In help page of `strptime`, arguments `%u` and `%w` can be used. Thus, with:

```
monday <- as.numeric(format(index(spyReturns), "%u") %in% "1")
```

We get

```
#  [1] 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
# [38] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
# ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data$weekday <- format(data$date, "%A")

# creating a dummy variable ###########
data$monday <- 0 
data[data$weekday == "Monday",]$monday <- 1
```

This is should solve the problem. In case if you need to create dummy for all the weekday, you can just use a loop to do the work.

Comment: Use `%in%` instead of `==`. You can use a vector with `%in%`. And `format(data$date, %A)` is not correct.

Comment: `"%A"` missed the `" "`. `%in%` can be good too. In case I have a vector of length more than 1 I always go with `%in%`. Since it is just one day. I chose `==`

Comment: Directly use `%in%`, no need for a `for` loop.

Comment: In case I need to create dummy's for `Tue, Wed and so on` as different columns, I might like to loop it over.